# Is Epiphany the only browser for Gnome supporting password storage in keyring?

Tags: linux, browser, passwords, gnome

Is Epiphany the only browser for Gnome supporting password storage in keyring?
Firefox and Chromium both seem to store login credentials in own storage thus limiting interoperability.

Comment: Chrome can store in the keyring as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so: https://github.com/mdlavin/firefox-gnome-keyring

Comment: Wow, it seems to be compatible with FF 6. It was 3.5 only a while ago. Amazing!

Answer (score 1):

[Midori](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php?/pages/midori_summary.html) isn't GNOME-specific, but there is a [gnome-keyring plugin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=49314) available for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, current Chrome builds also support Gnome keyring. It's been there at least for the last 12 months or so.